# Jquery is only submitting the first element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to store the products ID but it's only storing the first element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#driver").live('click', function(event){
    var product = $("#product").val();
    $("#stage").load('add-exec.php', {"product":product} );
  });
});
```

and here's the list

```
<?php

  $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";
  $query=mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td>
  <td>
    <input type="hidden" id="product" value="<?php echo $row['id_product'] ;?>" /><br />
    <div id="stage"></div> 
    <input type="button" id="driver" value="Add" />
</tr>
<?php

  }

?>
```

Comment: ID must be unique. Used class instead for multiple elements

Comment: Ive tried using classes didnt work for me @NorlihazmeyGhazali

Comment: @Erick jQuery will not be able to find anything in `style="display:none;` , it's really a bad suggestion

Comment: @Erick.... Yea hidden inputs exist. And they have for a long time now

Comment: I agree in @ElefantPhace because it you will not see that in actual view. But if you inspect elements you can see the hidden inputs.

Comment: @Erick the hidden aint the problem cause the first element is working perfectly
its just about the rest elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said ID must be unique. Used class instead for multiple elements. Change into this solution:

```
// change id into class
<input type="hidden" class="product" value="<?php echo $row['id_product'] ;?>" />     <br />
 <div id="stage"></div> 
 // i added btnAdd class
<input type="button" class="driver btnAdd" value="Add" />
```

And js should be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // attach click event on btnAdd class
    $(".btnAdd").live('click', function(event){
       // get product value using selector .prevAll(must be siblings)
       // and filter by it class
       var product = $(this).prevAll('.product').val();
       $("#stage").load('add-exec.php', {"product":product} );
    });
 });
```